# Create and fill with data UI only one time - Jetpack Compose & MVVM architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose

My App architecture is one activity, multiple fragments - every fragment has own `viewModel` and UI created using `@Compose`

Every viewModel has `State` for example:

```
class DiscountViewState {
    val couponList = mutableStateOf<List<CouponOffer>?>(null)
}
```

Discount screen has TabRow with two items.
One display list with coupons, second discounts offer.
List data comes from database (I fetch data in viewModel as you can see below, then I set data to viewModel state)

Everything works fine but the problem is when I jump between tabs or I open again DiscountScreen whole UI "flashes" and mutableStateOf() with list updates.
What I want to achive is to fetch data from databse only one time(during first open of Discount screen) and don't update whole UI when I jump between screens.

Fragment:

```
   class DiscountFragment : Fragment() {
        private val discountViewModel by viewModel<DiscountViewModel>()
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
                setContent { DiscountScreen(viewModel = discountViewModel) }
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
  class DiscountViewModel(
    private val couponService: FirebaseCouponService,
    private val discountMapper: DiscountMapper
) : ViewModel() {

    val actions = Channel<DiscountAction>()
    val state = DiscountViewState()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            couponService.getCoupons().collect {
                when (it) {
                    is SuccessCollection -> {
                        actions.trySend(SuccessCouponDownloaded(it.snapshot))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                actions.receiveAsFlow().collect { action ->
                    when (action) {
                        is SuccessCouponDownloaded -> {
                            state.couponList.value = discountMapper.toCouponList(action.couponList)
                        }

                        is UpdateTab -> {
                            when (action.index) {
                                0 -> state.currentTab.value = PROMOTIONS
                                1 -> state.currentTab.value = COUPONS
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {}
        }
    }

}

sealed class DiscountAction {
    data class UpdateTab(val index: Int) : DiscountAction()
    data class SuccessCouponDownloaded(val couponList: QuerySnapshot) : DiscountAction()
}

class DiscountViewState {
    val currentTab = mutableStateOf(PROMOTIONS)
    val discountList = mutableStateOf<List<DiscountOffer>?>(null)
    val couponList = mutableStateOf<List<CouponOffer>?>(null)
}

enum class DiscountTabCategory {
    PROMOTIONS, COUPONS
}
```

@Composable screen:

```
@Composable
fun DiscountScreen(viewModel: DiscountViewModel) {
    val couponList = viewModel.state.couponList.value
    val discountList = viewModel.state.discountList.value

    Column {
        TextTabs(viewModel.actions)

        when (viewModel.state.currentTab.value) {
            DiscountTabCategory.PROMOTIONS -> discountsSection(discountList, viewModel.actions)
            DiscountTabCategory.COUPONS -> couponSection(couponList, viewModel.actions)
        }
    }
}
```

Coupon list screen:

```
@Composable
fun couponSection(list: List<CouponOffer>?, action: Channel<DiscountAction>) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        list?.forEach {
            CouponItem(offer = it, likeButtonClick = { action.trySend(DiscountAction.LikeCouponOffer(it)) })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well there really is no point using `MutableState` if you do not want regular updates to your data. Just initialise it as a regular list

Comment: Why on earth are you using Fragments and Compose in the same app? Are you trying to slowly migrate an older app over to Compose?

Comment: @MARSK User can like some offer and when it happens I run in my ViewModel:
discountService.likeDiscountOffer(offer.id)
state.discountList.value!!.find { it.id == offer.id }?.likedByUser = true
and then I update thumb up icon for that specific offer item in my UI

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes I"m. I'm still using navigation.xml file where I define fragment's destination. I thought keeping fragments but changing xml to Compose is good solution. Browsing Google's Compose samples makes me confused. There is a lot different navigation, dependenncy injection, state handling approaches. Is there any simple and clear sample with Compose + Coroutines + MVVM recommended for Android development in the end of 2021?

Comment: Why not just take the [state codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state)? It contains updated stuff regarding Compose + MVVM. For the coroutines, there's the code-along from Android Developers.

Comment: About the comment meant for me, it is so confusing. I think you are not clear with the basics so just take the codelabs I suggested. Please don't try to rush past them — take them in.

Comment: Try Jetmagic. It's an open source framework that works with Compose but lets you develop responsive apps: https://github.com/JohannBlake/Jetmagic